# Is there any way to clear the session on a browser or tab close in Django as SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True is not working at all?

Tags: django

When I close a tab or browser and then I run the application again opening the browser again, the previous session remains active. I tried SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True in settings.py file in the project directory as per the Django documentation. Nothing works. Even the existing solutions in stackoverflow does not work. Is there any way to clear the session on a browser or tab close in Django?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through some web sources, and the reason could be that your session already existed before you set up SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE. Try to run
python manage.py clearsessions

Comment: I have already tried with python manage.py clearsessions which definitely clears the session. But is there any way to automate the task, i.e., log out when browser tab or window is closed.